# Make Primefaces file upload button to work, in a primefaces + spring website when CSRF protection is enabled without avoiding the protection

Tags: spring-security, primefaces, csrf

I have a demo application consisting of one form (dashboard.xhtml) which allows user to select a file and then add a row to a table. To do this, it has two Primefaces File upload buttons, the first uses simple mode to load files, the second uses advanced mode.

[image]

When CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) protection (http.csrf().disable(); in WebSecurityConfigurer) is disabled, both buttons work fine, but as soon as I Enable CSRF protection (by commenting out the line http.csrf().disable(); ) the simple mode button stops working.
Application is built with Maven and JSF 2.3.14, Spring 5.3.27 and Primefaces 12.0.0 frameworks.

screenshot.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried to use JSF upload button, it is working fine but the designed is not aligned with Primefaces simple mode button and I'm not able to modify it.

Comment: Can you share a sample project please and add to https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/11422 ?
Otherwise hard to fix it.

Comment: I did not find a way to share it from stack. this is google drive link for sample project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yI8TASst-Ik8v4Mr9qg0jVG69wChfrM8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed for PrimeFaces 13.0.6: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/11427